# What does buildToolsVersion in build.gradle file actually do?

Tags: android, android-build, android-6.0-marshmallow

According to https://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/build-tools.html, this version added support for Android 6.0 (which contains the new requestPermission methods).

```
Revision 23.0.0 (August 2015) 
    Added support
    for the Android 6.0 (API level 23) release.
```

I am using the new requestPermission method for android 6.0, but did not update the buildToolsVersion - yet the programs still works, when I expect the build process to fail (see attached image).

so the question is: what exactly does buildToolsVersion do? I like to learn why did the version 22.0.1 work when it shouldn't? Did android studio bypass the values in the build.gradle file?

[image]

relevant section of build.gradle

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    compileOptions {
        encoding "UTF-8"
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


    defaultConfig {
        //Minimum FROYO
        minSdkVersion 4
        targetSdkVersion 23


<snip off unrelated parts>

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'

    //    ads: google play
    googlePlayCompile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    googlePlayCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'

    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**EDIT**
the answer in [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24521017/android-gradle-buildtoolsversion-vs-compilesdkversion) says that i have to use buildToolsVersion >= compileSdkVersion to use the new features. Yet I'm using the new features without updating the buildToolsVersion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24521017/android-gradle-buildtoolsversion-vs-compilesdkversion

Comment: @Amiya: this is where i got stumped... "You can use a higher version of the build-tools than your compileSdkVersion, in order to pick up new/better compiler while not changing what you build your app against."  my buildTool version is lower than the compileSdkVersion (and I am using the new features in the compileSdkVersion that shouldn't exist in the older buildTool)

Answer (score 0):

It is version of the compilers For each API level. for example if we use  compileSDKversion 20 the we can use buildToolsVersion 20.0.0 or above.