# What is the buildToolsVersion for android SDK 24?

Tags: android, build-tools, android-buildconfig

There's not much I can say about this. Oh well. Google released a new version of android called Nougat (android N). It is compileSdkVersion 24. However, on the [build tools page](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html) in the official documentation, it is not mentioned.

I want to give my app to 100% of the people using Google Play Store, which includes android N users.

tl;dr: What should I fill in the buildToolsVersion field?

Thanks.

Comment: if your sdk fully upgraded, then there is no need to ask this question, bcz android studio automatically set the latest version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`buildToolsVersion` should be set to `25` and `25.0.0`, as seen below:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

You can get the latest buildToolsVersion from SDK Manager in Android Studio.

Comment: we need useLibrary?

Comment: @petnamedsteve Which type lib using requirement.

Comment: @petnamedsteve Library using..... apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
    }

Comment: How did you get **24.0.2**??  Android Studio tells me it is not available.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky - Open the SDK Manager, then Launch Standalone SDK Manager, and you should see it under Tools along with the review number

Comment: 24.0.3 now available

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky latest version can be found using https://stackoverflow.com/a/39239240/3496570 and always try to set it with latest version

Answer (score 18):

**buildToolsVersion**

Using android gradle plugin `version > 3` you can remove the **android.buildToolsVersion** property

Quoting from the [*New Features* section](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#new_features) of the [*Android Gradle plugin release notes* for version 3.0.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#3-0-0):

> You no longer need to specify a version for the build tools. By default, the plugin automatically uses the minimum required build tools version for the version of Android plugin you're using.

[[minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion, compileSdkVersion]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47269079/4770877)

Comment: this should be at the top!