# Why I can't use low version buildTools?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build-tools

When I use 25.0.0, my project appear some bug(Floating Action Button doesn't show). But I can choice low version.

**Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (24.0.3) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 25.0.0**

Comment: Did you try 25.0.1?

Comment: Yes, It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+' to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2' , and now ,I can use 24.0.3

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you have a `build.gradle` file that defines `buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"`. But you only have version 24.0.3 installed.

Either upgrade your build tools by installing a newer version using `Tools/Android/SDK Manager/SDK Tools` or change the requirements on the app's `build.gradle` file to require the version you seem to have (24.0.3).

Comment: I have installed both 24.0.3 and 25.0.0. Before version 25.0.0 released. I use version 24.0.3 and it works well. When I updated 25.0.0 on November 16th, I can't use 24.0.3 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `compileSdkVersion` does not overlap with your `buildToolsVersion`. 
What I do in my project is I match the `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion`. Looks like this.

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Also, you can always check for updates from the SDK Manager in Android Studio.

Please take a look at this also, 
[What is the buildToolsVersion for android SDK 24?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588264/what-is-the-buildtoolsversion-for-android-sdk-24)

Cheers!

Comment: compileSdkVersion is 24 always.