# difference between compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion in android studio..?

Tags: android

hiii
    i'm new in android development.Can anyone tell me what is compileSdkVersion and 
buildTollsVersion defined in build tools version.

```
  compileSdkVersion 24
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```

is this a correct definition..?
if not then what it will cause..?

please help
thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android gradle: buildtoolsVersion vs compileSdkVersion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24521017/android-gradle-buildtoolsversion-vs-compilesdkversion)

Comment: follow this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24521017/android-gradle-buildtoolsversion-vs-compilesdkversion

Answer (score 0):

`compileSdkVersion` is the API version of Android that you compile against.

`buildToolsVersion` is the version of the compilers (aapt, dx, renderscript compiler, etc...) that you want to use. For each API level (starting with 18), there is a matching .0.0 version.

Comment: it is reasonable to reference the source when you quote someone's answer, btw

Comment: @user12345 Please do not overuse formatting, codeformatting alone is enough here. *(I will remove that comment when you acknowledged it, so remove yours as well if you add a comment)*