# Android: Build Tool Version vs Compile SDK Version

Tags: android, build.gradle, build-tools

We have an android app where we had both `compile SDK version` and `Build tool version` at 24. We had to update the android `com.android.support:design` version from 24.0.0 to 25.0.0. In this case, it was asked to update the `compile SDK version` into 25 from 24, but did not say anything about `Build Tool Version`.

Normally, how does the `Build Tool Version` and `Compile SDK version` work? `Build Tool Version` is in a lower version than `Compile SDK version`, any possible errors (run time or whatever, either in android playstore or development environment)

### Update

This question is not a duplicate, [the suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24521017/android-gradle-buildtoolsversion-vs-compilesdkversion) is about the differences between the SDK and Build tool version and also about having a higher build tool version with lower sdk version; this is the exact opposite of what I am asking, higher SDK with lower build tool version.

Comment: There was a nice answer for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24523113/1848157

Comment: pl provide your build.gradle file here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android gradle: buildtoolsVersion vs compileSdkVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24521017/android-gradle-buildtoolsversion-vs-compilesdkversion)

Comment: @RakshitNawani: You need to look at both questions before being so quick to mark something duplicate. In where they have discussed about the specific question I mentioned? Even in the answer they are talking about the other way around, having a higher build version with lower SDK. Reporting the post for the ignorance.

Comment: @PeakGen Google recommends to use last version of build tools with any compile/target sdk, because new build tools may have fixes for some issues

Comment: There is no reason to use ole build tools. Just use always the latest version. Why should you use a buildtools < compileSdk?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti: Finally, a good comment. Actually that is because I am using couple of libraries from both native android and third parties. Sometimes when the versions change, I have seen the libraries also showing errors saying they should be updated, when updated we find some methods etc no longer exists. Even though this didn't happen to me yet, kind of worried as i'm in a production environment.

Comment: @PeakGen Only changing the compileSdk you can break your build because it introduces same changes. The buildtools instead doesn't change the compilation so it is always a good practice to use the latest version.